# When is variance of sample maximum greater than unconditional variance?

Tags: probability, variance, order-statistics, extreme-value

Let $X_1$,...,$X_n$ be $n$ i.i.d. RVs with continuous distribution $F$. Further let $X_{(1)}$,...,$X_{(n)}$ be the associated order statistics such that $X_{(1)}<X_{(2)}<...<X_{(n)}$.

Under what conditions on $F$ and $n$ is $Var(X_{(n)}) > Var(X)$?

Comment: I am assuming that $Var(X)$ is the identical variance of any of the $X_i$? If so, why do you think $Var(X_{(n)})$ would be greater than $Var(X)$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. $Var(X)$ is the unconditional variance of $F$.

I don't think $Var(X_{(n)})$ will be greater than $Var(X)$, generally. For example, the max of a set of i.i.d. normal RV's has lower variance than the i.i.d. normals. But, for some distributions, (e.g. exponential or t with 3 dfs) the variance of the max exceeds the variance of the i.i.d. draws.

I'm looking for a general rule as to when this will be the case.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can have weird reversals for finite $n$, but at least for $n$ large you should be able to get insight from the Fisher-Tipett-Gnedenko theorem on the distribution of the maximum: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theory#Univariate_theory